# React - Use property from another component

Tags: reactjs

I have a terminal component that render a terminale emulator.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { XTerm } from '../../node_modules/react-xterm';
import os from 'os';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../../node_modules/xterm/dist/xterm.css';

const pty = require('node-pty');

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state;
};

class Terminal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.xtermLoaded = false;
    this.ptyProcess = null;
    this.term = null;

    this.shell = process.env[os.platform() === 'win32' ? 'COMSPEC' : 'SHELL'];
    this.ptyProcess = pty.spawn(this.shell, [], {
      name: 'xterm-color',
      cols: 50,
      rows: 30,
      cwd: process.cwd(),
      env: process.env
    });
  }

  bindXterm(xterm) {
    if (!xterm || this.xtermLoaded) return;
    let term = xterm.getTerminal();
    if (!term.on) return;
    this.term = term;
    this.xtermLoaded = true;
    this.term.on('data', data => {
      this.ptyProcess.write(data);
    });
    this.ptyProcess.on('data', data => {
      this.term.write(data);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <XTerm style={{
        addons: ['fit', 'fullscreen'],
        overflow: 'hidden',
        position: 'relative',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
      }} ref={xterm => this.bindXterm(xterm)}/>

    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Terminal));
```

With this.ptyProcess.write(data), i can write new things into the terminal.
But how i can access to this.ptyProcess.write(data) from another component ?

Can someone help me please ? :)

Thanks.

Comment: If that another component is child component for Terminal..you can pass `this.ptyProcess.write(data)` as props to child component

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. 
No, i want to be able to write data into the terminal from any component, child or not.

Comment: If so you need to write the function you want to access in the parent component of all the components and pass the same as props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using redux. Just include a dataForTerminal reducer that when changes, new data are written into the terminal.

So create an action creator for it and then you can call the action creator from any component

Comment: Hello,
How i can handle change of dataForTerminal in my terminal component ?

Comment: @laurentmichel you need to write redux action and call the same in all components

Comment: I am not familiar with these libraries (xterm and react-xterm), but after you setup the reducer and action creator you could try something like this: this.term.writeln(dataForTerminal ) within render. This is just to get the idea and check if it works. It is not a proper solution

Comment: Yeah it works nice !!
But if i want to launch two sames commands (ls for example) ?

i have this  : 
 const action = { type: 'LAUNCH_TERMINAL_COMMAND', value: 'ls \n' };
this.props.dispatch(action);

But if i execute two times this code, the state don't change the second time. 
Do i need to set the state to null before ?

Comment: I guess this is the quick fix, just dispatch 2 actions, one to make it null and one to issue the ls. Make sure to check if the dataForTerminal  is the same between renders, because if you won't check the component may re-render and execute the same command twice. If you dive into the libraries used and read the documentation i am sure that there are better solutions then this

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this component is created either by another component, or by a call to ReactDOM.Render(). You should make ptyProcess a member of the nearest common ancestor of all the components that need to access it, and then pass it down to them as part of the `props` object.

As a general rule in react, if a property needs to be shared by multiple child components, then you should "hoist" that property up into the parent component and pass it down to the children through `props`.